# how to retreive image in iPhone which is in binary format in server

Tags: iphone, ios4

In server, the image is stored in binary format. I have to retrieve the image in iphone using json. How can I do that?  Is it possible to do this using NSData also?

Comment: for API backend which language are you using php or any thing else

Comment: Why did you unaccept the answer? is there any wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to covert binary data to NSData like this:

```
NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithBase64EncodedString:yourelement];
UIImage *theImg = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
```

You would need MBBase64 class which is available here: https://github.com/jerrykrinock/CategoriesObjC

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the binary value from the server using json parsing and then convert that string to NSData.

This is the standard code used for converting the base64 string to NSData.

```
//MBBase64.h

@interface NSData (MBBase64)

+ (id)dataWithBase64EncodedString:(NSString *)string;     //  Padding '=' characters are optional. Whitespace is ignored.

@end


//MBBase64.m

static const char encodingTable[] =     "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";

@implementation NSData (MBBase64)

+ (id)dataWithBase64EncodedString:(NSString *)string;
{
    if (string == nil)
        [NSException raise:NSInvalidArgumentException format:nil];
    if ([string length] == 0)
        return [NSData data];

    static char *decodingTable = NULL;
    if (decodingTable == NULL)
    {
        decodingTable = malloc(256);
        if (decodingTable == NULL)
            return nil;
        memset(decodingTable, CHAR_MAX, 256);
        NSUInteger i;
        for (i = 0; i < 64; i++)
            decodingTable[(short)encodingTable[i]] = i;
        }    

    const char *characters = [string cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    if (characters == NULL)     //  Not an ASCII string!
        return nil;
    char *bytes = malloc((([string length] + 3) / 4) * 3);
    if (bytes == NULL)
        return nil;
    NSUInteger length = 0;

    NSUInteger i = 0;
    while (YES)
    {
        char buffer[4];
        short bufferLength;
        for (bufferLength = 0; bufferLength < 4; i++)
        {
            if (characters[i] == '\0')
                break;
            if (isspace(characters[i]) || characters[i] == '=')
                continue;
                buffer[bufferLength] = decodingTable[(short)characters[i]];
            if (buffer[bufferLength++] == CHAR_MAX)      //  Illegal character!
            {
                free(bytes);
                return nil;
            }
        }

        if (bufferLength == 0)
            break;
        if (bufferLength == 1)      //  At least two characters are needed to produce one byte!
        {
            free(bytes);
            return nil;
        }

        //  Decode the characters in the buffer to bytes.
        bytes[length++] = (buffer[0] << 2) | (buffer[1] >> 4);
        if (bufferLength > 2)
            bytes[length++] = (buffer[1] << 4) | (buffer[2] >> 2);
    if (bufferLength > 3)
        bytes[length++] = (buffer[2] << 6) | buffer[3];
    }

    realloc(bytes, length);
    return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:bytes length:length];
}

@end
```

Then load that  resulted NSdata in UIimageview

```
yourimageview.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:resultdata];
```